# Custom class in laravel 10 not found

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, namespaces, laravel-10

I have created a custom class in laravel 10 located in:

```
App\Helpers\CompletedOrders
```

The class contain this code:

```
<?
namespace App\Helpers\CompletedOrders;

class DeliverOrdersByMail
{

    public static function DeliverOrdersToCustomerMail($OrderID)
    {
        return "mail ok ". $OrderID;
    }

}
```

When I try to call the class on a file:

```
use App\Helpers\CompletedOrders\DeliverOrdersByMail;

Route::get('test', function(){
    DeliverOrdersByMail::DeliverOrdersToCustomerMail("fgzefef");
});
```

I'm getting an error that the class is not found!

> Class "App\Helpers\CompletedOrders\DeliverOrdersByMail" not found

Any solution please?

Comment: Try `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: @aynber i did still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP `short_open_tag(<?)` depricated.So you have use `<?php` instead of `<?`

> In PHP 7.4 short_open_tag remains enabled by default: Changing the
> default could result in code leaks during upgrades, if people rely on
> the default value rather than explicitly enabling them. Instead:
>
> - If short_open_tag is enabled and <? is used, a single deprecation notice is emitted.
> - If short_open_tag is enabled, but <? is never used, no deprecation notice is emitted (as before).
> - If short_open_tag is disabled, <? has no special meaning and is interpreted as plain text (as before).

**In PHP 8.0 the deprecation notice is converted into a parse error:**

> - If short_open_tag is enabled, the use of <? is a parse error.
> - If short_open_tag is disabled, <? has no special meaning (as before).

**In PHP 9.0 support for short_open_tag is dropped entirely:**

> - .<? never has special meaning, it is always interpreted as plain text.

Ref: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags_v2

Comment: wow, this didn't come in my mind at all that something like that would cause this problem. Thank you for saving me after 2 hours of trying lol